# TypeScript: Describe Object of Objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have an interface like this:

```
interface Student {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  year: number;
  id: number;
}
```

If I wanted to pass around an array of these objects I could simply write the type as `Student[]`.

Instead of an array, I'm using an object where student ids are keys and students are values, for easy look-ups.

```
let student1: Student;
let student2: Student;
let students = {001: student1, 002: student2 }
```

**Is there any way to describe this data structure as the type I am passing into or returning from functions?**

I can define an interface like this:

```
interface StudentRecord {
  id: number;
  student: Student
}
```

But that still isn't the type I want. I need to indicate I have an object *full of objects* that look like this, the same way `Student[]` indicates I have an array full of objects that look like this.

Comment: something like this: `let students: {[key: string]: Student} = ...`. Also, object keys cannot be numbers (but can be numeric strings).

Comment: Your only options here are using the answer @GetOffMyLawn suggested or alternatively using a `Map` - which is definitely a good fit! The type for that would be `Map<number, Student>`. You should note that `{ 1234: foo }` implicitly coerces '1234' to a string such that `{ "1234": foo }` and `{ 1234: foo }` are equivalent. If you need to maintain numbers as keys you must use a Map.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types

Answer (score 74, accepted):

you can simply make the key dynamic:

```
interface IStudentRecord {
   [key: string]: Student
}
```

Comment: @DustinMichels if it's the correct answer, please mark the answer as accepted by pressing the green tick below the voting options on this answer :)

Comment: What messerbill is calling "dynamic" is generally referred to as index signature (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

Answer (score 18):

Use the built-in `Record` type:

```
type StudentsById = Record<Student['id'], Student>;
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using a Record over the [indexable types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) solution?

Comment: `Record` is aware of your `keyofStringsOnly` setting. If it's turned on, it will only allow the keys of type `string` (which is what JavaScript does to keys in runtime).

Comment: This is way more TS way :D

Comment: dot notation is not working for this.

Answer (score 18):

There's a few ways to go about this:

### String Index Signature

As mentioned by [@messerbill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733365/79247) you can use index signature for this:

```
interface StudentRecord {
    [P: string]: Student;
}
```

Or if you want to be more cautious: (see caveat below)

```
interface StudentRecordSafe {
    [P: string]: Student | undefined;
}
```

### Mapped Type Syntax

Alternatively, you can also use [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) syntax:

```
type StudentRecord = {
    [P in string]: Student;
}
```

or the more cautious version: (see caveat below)

```
type StudentRecordSafe = {
    [P in String]?: Student
}
```

It's very similar to string index signature, but can use other things in replace of `string`, such as a union of specific strings.  There's also a utility type, `Record` which is defined as:

```
type Record<K extends string, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
}
```

which means you can also write this as `type StudentRecord = Record<string, Student>`.  (Or `type StudentRecordSafe = Partial<Record<string, Student>>`)  (This is my usual preference, as it's IMO, easier to read and write Record than the long-hand index or type mapping syntax)

#### A Caveat with Index Signature and Mapped Type Syntax

A caveat with both of these is that they're "optimistic" about the existence of students for a given id.  They assume that for any string key, there's a corresponding `Student` object, even when that's not the case: for example, this compiles for both:

```
const students: StudentRecord = {};
students["badId"].id // Runtime error: cannot read property id of undefind
```

Using the corresponding "cautious" versons:

```
const students: StudentRecordSafe = {}
students["badId"].id;  // Compile error, object is potentially undefined
```

It's a *bit* more annoying to use, especially if you know that you'll only be looking up ids that exist, but it's definitely type safer.

**As of version 4.1** Typescript now has a flag called `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` which fixes this issue - any accesses to an index signature like this will now be considered potentially undefined when the flag is enabled.  This makes the 'cautious' version unnecessary if the flag is on.  (The flag is *not* included automatically by `strict: true` and must be directly enabled in the tsconfig)

### Map objects

A slight code change, but a proper `Map` object can be used, too, and it's always the "safe" version, where you have to properly check that thing`

```
type StudentMap = Map<string, Student>;
const students: StudentMap = new Map();
students.get("badId").id; // Compiler error, object might be undefined
```

Answer (score -8):

instate of let students = {001: student1, 002: student2 } you could just say 
let students = {student1, student2 } then access them by their index like students[0] and students[1] and if you need info out of the student you can do that like students[0].firstName

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking